# Datatable Header shrinking when table is updated

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I have a problem with "DataTable" table. The header is not aligned when I refresh/update the table. Example is on the picture below.

The table is initialized in the beginning and is placed in a dropdown field. Then it's updated with function that clears, updates the table and draws table. If the table is being updated and the button to show the dropdown filed in which table is placed is pressed, then situation in image bellow will happen. After the update, the header is automatically corrected to normal width.

[image]

HTML part:

```
<table id="mainTable" class="dataTable" style="width:100%;">
    <thead bgcolor="#fd7e14" class="maintablehead">
        <th>Coin</th>
        <th>Vol</th>
        <th>% Change</th>
        <th>Last price</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="mainTableBody">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Table declaration part:

```
var a = $('#mainTable').DataTable({
data: dataInput,
columns: [
    { data: "symbol" },
    { data: "vol" },
    { data: "change"},
    { data: "price" }
],
"columnDefs": [
    { "type": "any-number", targets: 1 },
    { "type": "any-number", targets: 2 },
    { "type": "any-number", targets: 3 },
    { "className": "dt-center", "targets": "_all" },
    {
        targets:2, render: function ( data, type, row ) {
            var color = 'black';
            if (data > 0) {
                color = 'green';
            } 
            if (data < 0) {
                color = 'red';
            }
            if (data == 0) {
                color = 'black';
            }
            return '<span style="color:' + color + '">' + data + '</span>';
            }
    }
],
"paging": false,
"info": false,
"order": [[0, "desc"]],
"scrollY": "400px",
"scrollCollapse": false,
"auto-width": true,
"fixedHeader": true,
"language": {
    "zeroRecords": "No symbol found on selected exchange",
    "search": "Enter symbol:",
},
"initComplete": function () {
    $(document).on("click", " #mainTable tbody tr[role='row']", function () {
        var id = $(this).children('td:first-child').text();
        document.getElementById("coin-name").innerHTML = id;
        widget.onChartReady(function () {
            var chart = widget.activeChart();
            chart.setSymbol(id);
        })
    });
},
});
```

I refresh the table every 10 seconds with following code.

```
var datatable = $('#mainTable').dataTable().api();
datatable.clear();
datatable.rows.add(dataInput);
datatable.columns.adjust().draw(false);
```

How to prevent this from happening? I have searched and tried many solutions in datatable forums, but nothing works. Setting the width of the thead to 100% doesnt work.

I am using 2 tables and both are having the same problems.

Answer (score 0):

try datatable.empty() instead of a clear.  This looks like it's resetting all of the element attributes.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/empty/

try emptying the ID directly 

$('#mainTable').empty()

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using Scroller extension with `scrollY` option, use [`scroller.measure()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/scroller.measure%28%29) API method instead of `columns.adjust()`.

```
var datatable = $('#mainTable').DataTable();
datatable.clear();
datatable.rows.add(dataInput);
datatable.scroller.measure().draw(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment out any of the scrollY/scrollX or sScrollX/sScrollY in your code and swap "scrollCollapse": false, with "bScrollCollapse": true, I don't feel you will require to use
"auto-width": true,
"fixedHeader": true, after this, hope it works :D best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

I was fighting against this error (actually believe it's a bug), and finally found a possible solution.

If you can sort by columns, just click any header element (from dataTable) using the html DOM, once you get the whole rows that you want to show.

```
let element = document.querySelector('th');
element.click();
```